# Custom fetch with promise fails

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I want to implement `fetch` method by myself with promises with builder pattern, the backend is fine. I tested it with postman and it works fine. I don't know what could be, I tried everything but I don't get any data.

I think the problem is that it doesn't properly transform my data to JSON or something.

Any help will be appreciated.

```js
class Fetch {
    constructor(){
        this.url = null;
        this.result = null;
        this.method = null;
        this.header = null;
        this.body = null;
    }
    call(){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fetch(this.url, 
                  {method: this.method, header: this.header, body: this.body})
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    this.result = data;
                    console.log(data);
                    resolve(data);
                })
        })
    }
}
class FetchBuilder {
    constructor(){
        this.customFetch = new Fetch();
    }
    request(url){
        this.flag = true;
        this.customFetch.url = url;
        return this;
    }
    method(method){
        this.customFetch.method = method;
        return this;
    }
    header(header){
        this.customFetch.header = header;
        return this;
    }
    body(body){
        if(!this.flag){
            this.customFetch.body = JSON.stringify(body);
        }
        return this;
    }
    query(obj){
    }
    send(){
        this.customFetch.call();
    }
}

const fetchObj = new FetchBuilder();
fetchObj.request('https://node-app-test-picsart.herokuapp.com/signin')
        .method('POST')
        .header({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        })
        .body({
            email: 'bro@gmail.com',
            password: 'bro'
        })
        .send()
```

**Header:**
[image]

**Body**
[image]

Comment: Does the backend have CORS headers set?

Comment: @GuyIncognito I don't think so, I tried only with Content type header and it works fine in postman

Comment: Please post text, not images of text.

Comment: @DaveNewton the text is in the code

Comment: @DaveNewton the same body and headers, look at the bottom of my code

Comment: See [Why doesn’t Postman get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when my JavaScript code does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-doesn-t-postman-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on)

Comment: @GuyIncognito okay, what could be the problem in my code

Comment: @GuyIncognito forget about postman

Comment: Is it intended that `if(!this.flag){` is executed when `this.flag` is true?

Comment: The problem could be that you don't have CORS headers set on the backend.

Comment: @trincot yes it is

Comment: Then what is the purpose of the `.body()` call here? It doesn't do anything...

Comment: @trincot that's in case if the response is not good then I will get back my body

Comment: @GuyIncognito thank you, I will ask a guy who is responsible for backend :)

Comment: I don't see how that can work, as `.body()` is doing nothing to the state of your object. The literal you pass as argument is lost in oblivion.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue lies in either the `this.flag = true` or `if (!this.flag) {` line what causes the `body` argument passed in the `.body()` method to be lost. So you're code is doing what you want but just not in the right way, as you are expecting a package to be sent to the endpoint.

So either change the boolean:

```
...
request(url) {
  this.flag = false;
  this.customFetch.url = url;
  return this;
}
...
```

Or the condition checking the boolean. The rest of your code works as expected.

```
...
body(body) {
  if (this.flag) {
    this.customFetch.body = JSON.stringify(body);   
  }
  return this;
}
...
```

Run the code below with the **network** tab in your developer tools opened to see that a request is made with the body you want to send.

```js
class Fetch {
  constructor() {
    this.url = null;
    this.result = null;
    this.method = null;
    this.header = null;
    this.body = null;
  }
  call() {
    return fetch(this.url, {
        method: this.method,
        header: this.header,
        body: this.body
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.result = data;
        console.log(data);
        return data;
      })
  }
}

class FetchBuilder {
  constructor() {
    this.customFetch = new Fetch();
  }
  request(url) {
    this.flag = true;
    this.customFetch.url = url;
    return this;
  }
  method(method) {
    this.customFetch.method = method;
    return this;
  }
  header(header) {
    this.customFetch.header = header;
    return this;
  }
  body(body) {
    if (this.flag) {
      this.customFetch.body = JSON.stringify(body);
    }
    return this;
  }
  query(obj) {}
  send() {
    this.customFetch.call();
  }
}

const fetchObj = new FetchBuilder();
fetchObj.request('https://node-app-test-picsart.herokuapp.com/signin')
  .method('POST')
  .header({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
  })
  .body({
    email: 'bro@gmail.com',
    password: 'bro'
  })
  .send()
```

In your `Fetch().call()` just return the `fetch` as it already returns a `Promise`, wrapping it like this would be an anti-pattern. You could also use the *async / await* syntax.